# CodeIgniter: Allowed memory exhausted

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working in CodeIgniter. What I am trying to do is reading an Excel file and saving to a database. To read the Excel file, I am using [this library](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Excel-Reader-Class). After uploading, while reading the Excel file, I am getting this error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 71 bytes) in /home/webscwi1/public_html/projects/OnlineExam/application/libraries/excel_reader.php on line 430

Anyhow, I can change the memory size from 12Mb to 512Mb, I'm still getting the same error. I don't know what is the exact error and I want to know whether this is a server error or a problem in the code.

Additional info: If I upload the file with 15 rows, it's working fine, but if I upload with 90 rows in Excel I am getting this error:

```
 $this->load->library('excel_reader');
 $this->excel_reader->read('question/'.$filename);
 $worksheet = $this->excel_reader->worksheets[0];
```

Thanks to all.

Comment: How big is the file you're reading? Does it happen even with smaller files? Are you using loops? You should provide more info...

Comment: thanks for the reply, the file size was 64kb only

Comment: please check the excel library. I am getting error in the excel library. https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Excel-Reader-Class

Comment: After upload, i am just calling the library to read the file

Comment: No thanks, I'm not going to debug a whole third party library just to help you on a vague problem; I skimmed the issues submitted and saw nothing about out of memory issues, there must be something in how you call the library or in your code, or in your file. You could try asking the developer, or submitting an issue report on that, but with a test case that shows how and when the problem occurs

Comment: i understand, you can't check the whole library, but i got the issue there. but i am getting problem there. If i upload with 15 rows in excel it's working fine, but if i upload 90 rows in excel i am getting this problem

Comment: Can you please show us the code where you read the excel file? Maybe we can find something in there... .

Comment: ok i added the file read code

Comment: first I would do a

    echo phpinfo();

and double check the memory_limit as there used to be multiple php.ini files

Comment: ok thanks, i will do it now

Comment: hey memory limit was 128M, check out this link http://webscarlets.in/projects/OnlineExam/test.php

Comment: Hmm. It just seems to  be a server problem. Can you increase the memory limit to 512 MB and then check it e.g. with the output from phpinfo(). So, you can verify it already has more memory availible.

Comment: sorry, can you tell me. how can i increase the size?

Comment: can i increase via htaccess or php.ini file?

Comment: just curious, why are you not importing the excel file straight into your database, via phpMyAdmin or something?

Comment: i changed to 512 now getting this error. Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 71 bytes) in /home/webscwi1/public_html/projects/OnlineExam/application/libraries/excel_reader.php on line 430

Comment: he hui: no, i can't do like this, this is a for online exam. So admin will upload 100 or 200 questions from the excel file

Comment: It's most likely an issue with the excel reader class. Have you tried using another third party class?

Comment: did you checked error logs? both ci logs and server logs? php logs? anyway i tink you are running a huge script so you get more then 512mb of memory

Answer (score 11):

You should increase your Memory limit:

- editing your php.ini file

  memory_limit = 512M

OR

- including this line on the top of your script

  ini_set("memory_limit","512M");

You should also check if this lines are on your .htaccess:

```
php_value memory_limit <value>
php_value upload_max_filesize <value>
```

Their values override the php configuration. So they should reflect your needs, or simply be removed.

Comment: I was able to use this command in specific scenarios in the PHP code that required more memory:  
  ini_set("memory_limit","512M");    It actually didn't have to be at the top of the file, and was even working inside a function!

Answer (score 1):

You should add attribute php_value on your file **NameOfProject/.htaccess**

> `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
>   php_value memory_limit 256M 
>   </IfModule>`

Answer (score 0):

This memory overflow can be the automatic save of the last query, you can so `$this->db->save_queries = false;` or change in the file config/database.php for `'save_queries' => FALSE,`