# my code does not work as i am new to codeigneter so having trouble with this

Tags: php, codeigniter

views/image.php

```
  <form action="upload1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h3>Image Upload Form</h3>
   <input type="file" name="pic" tabindex="2" required>
   <input type="text" name="alt" placeholder="Image Alt Text" tabindex="1" 
    required>
  <button type="submit" id="img-submit" data-submit="Sending">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

controller/upload.php

```
function upload1()

   {
     $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
            $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size']             = 100;
            $config['max_width']            = 1024;
            $config['max_height']           = 768;
             $data = array(
    'image_url' => $this->input->$_FILES['pic']['name'],
    'alt' => $this->input->post('alt')
  );
    $result = $this->upload_m->upload1($data);
   }
```

model/upload_m.php

```
 <?php
 class upload_m extends CI_Model {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}
 function upload1($data)
  { 
   $data ['image_url']= $this->upload1($data);
  $data ['alt']= $this->input->post('alt');
       $this->db->insert('image', $data);
    redirect(base_url() . 'index.php/upload/', 'refresh');

  }
 }
   ?>
```

when i click on the submit button upload1 function call and it gives error array to string conversion
and in model
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter\application\models\upload_m.php on line 12

Can anyone detect and tell me what mistake I am doing?

Comment: not sure, but you call $data ['image_url']= $this->upload1($data); in upload_m, but the upload1() method returns nothing, so you essentially blank that value, or turn it into a bool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your controller as below:

```
function upload1() {
    $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size']             = 100;
    $config['max_width']            = 1024;
    $config['max_height']           = 768;

    $data = array(
        'image_url' => $_FILES['pic']['name'],
        'alt' => $this->input->post('alt')
    );

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('pic')) {
        //$error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        // use $error by passing to a view. Please see the documentation.
    } else {
        $result = $this->upload_m->upload1($data);
        redirect(base_url() . 'index.php/upload/', 'refresh');
    }
}
```

and the model:

```
class upload_m extends CI_Model
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function upload1($data)
    {
        $image_data = $this->upload->data();
        $data['image_url'] = $image_data['file_name'];
        $data['alt']       = $this->input->post('alt');
        return $this->db->insert('image', $data);        
    }
}
```

Note: You should not redirect inside the model.

```
'image_url' => $this->input->$_FILES['pic']['name'],
```

Above line is syntactically wrong. And below line in model make a recursive call

```
$data ['image_url']= $this->upload1($data);
```

Comment: use your code no error shown and also image is not saved to db

Comment: can you add below code to under this if condition `if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('pic')) {`

`var_dump($error);`

Comment: it resulting NULL

Comment: Are you sure that error array is null? Because if that upload configuration has an errors that if condition evaluate as true. So it should not be empty.
Try `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and check you upload configuration is correct according to the documentation. I hope you will fix this issue.

Comment: yes it results NULL and now where i should check configuration ?

Comment: are you sure your `$config['upload_path']` is correct?

Comment: i have created a folder name uploads in  codeingniter/uploads

Comment: thank you so much for your help  your suggestions worked for me

Comment: Nice to hear that. If you think suitable answer is my answer you can mark it as well ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

**In Controller**

```
function upload1()
{
    $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size']             = 100;
    $config['max_width']            = 1024;
    $config['max_height']           = 768;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('pic'))
    {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $this->load->view('ViewName', $error);
    }
    else
    {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            $alt = $this->input->post('alt');

            $this->upload_m->upload1($data, $alt);

            $this->load->view('successView', $data);
    }

}
```

**In Model**

```
function upload1($data, $alt)
{ 
    $data['upload_path']= $this->upload1($data);
    $data['alt']= $alt;

    $this->db->insert('image', $data);
}
```

---

Links

1. [CodeIgniter: Allowed memory exhausted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14701398/codeigniter-allowed-memory-exhausted)
2. [File Uploading Class](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html)

Comment: i use your code but its not showing any error as well as not uploading the image

Comment: my problem was solved that day thank you for your help and guide